# ngCordova plugin zip deosn't works with Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I spent an entire day trying to resolve this problem.
File is downloaded and stored in device memory, than is unziped.

```
// Url of file for download
  var url = "http://exapmle/someUrl";

  // File names only
  var file = "aaa.zip";

  $scope.contenutoDownload = function () {      
    // Save location
    var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory  + file;

    // Use cordovaFileTransfer to store the file in the device storage
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url + file, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {

        console.log('File downloaded. ' + JSON.stringify(result));

        $cordovaZip
          .unzip(
            result.nativeURL,
            cordova.file.dataDirectory 
          ).then(function () {

            console.log('cordovaZip success');
            //Delete zip file
            if(cordova.platformId == 'ios') {
              $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.tempDirectory,file);
            } else {
              $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory,file);
            }

          }, function () {

            console.log('cordovaZip error');

          }, function (progressEvent) {

            console.log(progressEvent);

            }
          );

      },  function (error) {

        console.log('Error with cordovaFileTransfer');

      },  function (progress) {

        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.downloadProgress = ((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100) + '%';

      });

    });

  };
```

Result is always 'cordovaZip error', if try to pass any argument to the function (the error's one) no object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your paths are incorrect

```
    $cordovaZip
      .unzip(
        result.nativeURL,
        cordova.file.dataDirectory 
      ).then(function () {
```

Should or could be

```
    $cordovaZip
      .unzip(
        targetPath,
        cordova.file.dataDirectory 
      ).then(function () {
```

not sure what the nativeURL gives I would console all of these out to see what matches - also thought nativeURL was a method nativeURL()